# Need to replace spaces inside string with percentual symbol Java

Tags: java

I need to replace the spaces inside a string with the % symbol but I'm having some issues, what I tried is:

```
imageUrl = imageUrl.replace(' ', "%20");
```

But It gives me an error in the replace function.

Then:

```
imageUrl = imageUrl.replace(' ', "%%20");
```

But It still gives me an error in the replace function.

The I tried with the unicode symbol:

```
imageUrl = imageUrl.replace(' ', (char) U+0025 + "20");
```

But it still gives error.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: There is no `replace(char, String)` method in String. You can try with `replace(String, String)`. Remember that `'` can wrap only one character, and `"` represents String.

Comment: can you try `imageUrl.replace("\\s", "%20");`

Comment: @Amit.rk3 `replace` doesn't use regex syntax. You may want to change it to `replaceAll`.

Comment: If it represent's an URL, you need not be replacing it at all. Java will automatically do it for you when you use it somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `String.replace(String, String)` is the method you want.

**replace**

```
imageUrl.replace(' ', "%");
```

**with**

```
imageUrl.replace(" ", "%");

System.out.println("This is working".replace(" ", "%"));
```

I suggest you to use a `URL Encoder` for Encoding `Strings` in java.

```
String searchQuery = "list of banks in the world";
String url = "http://mypage.com/pages?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(searchQuery, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: ok that was stupid by me :P thank you! will accept as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into issues like this in the past with certain frameworks. I don't have enough of your code to know for sure, but what might be happening is whatever http framework you are using, in my case it was spring, is encoding the URL again. I spent a few days trying to solve a similar problem where I thought that string replace and the URI.builder() was broken. What ended up being the problem   was that my http framework had taken my encoded url, and encoded it again. that means that any place it saw a "%20", it would see the '%' charictor and switch it out for '%' http code, "%25", resulting in. "%2520". The request would then fail because %2520 didn't translate into the space my server was expecting. While the issue apeared to be one of my encoding not working, it was really an issue of encoding too many times. I have an example from some working code in one of my projects below

```
//the Url of the server
String fullUrl = "http://myapiserver.com/path/";

//The parameter to append. contains a space that will need to be encoded
String param 1 = "parameter 1"

//Use Uri.Builder to append parameter
Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse(fullUrl).buildUpon();
uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("parameter1",param1);

/* Below is where it is important to understand how your
http framework handles unencoded url. In my case, which is Spring 
framework, the urls are encoded when performing requests. 
The result is that a url that is already encoded will be 
encoded twice. For instance, if you're url is

     "http://myapiserver.com/path?parameter1=param 1"

and it needs to be read by the server as 
     "http://myapiserver.com/path?parameter1=param%201"

it makes sense to encode the url using URI.builder().append, or any valid
solutions listed in other posts. However, If the framework is already 
encoding your url, then it is likely to run into the issue where you
accidently encode the url twice: Once when you are preparing the URL to be 
sent, and once again when you are sending the message through the framework.

this results in sending a url that looks like
"http://myapiserver.com/path?parameter1=param%25201"
where the '%' in "%20" was replaced with "%25", http's representation of '%' 
when what you wanted was 
"http://myapiserver.com/path?parameter1=param%201"

this can be a difficult bug to squash because you can copy the url in the 
debugger prior to it being sent and paste it into a tool like fiddler and 
have the fiddler request work but the program request fail. 

since my http framework was already encoding the urls, I had to unencode the
 urls after appending the parameters so they would only be encoded once.
I'm not saying it's the most gracefull solution, but the code works.
*/
        String finalUrl = uriBuilder.build().toString().replace("%2F","/")
 .replace("%3A", ":").replace("%20", " ");

            //Call the server and ask for the menu. the Menu is saved to a    string
           //rest.GET() uses spring framework. The url is encoded again as 
part of the framework.
            menuStringFromIoms = rest.GET(finalUrl);
```

There is likely a more graceful way to keep a url from encoding twice.  I hope this example helps point you on the right direction or eliminate a possability. Good luck.

Comment: My problem was that the webservice sometimes returned an image url with spaces inside (because on the ftp some images are saved with spaces inside their name) and the library I use in order to download the images couldn't retrieve the image because of the spaces inside the name. Replacing them with "%20" did the trick. Ty for your explanation though

Answer (score 0):

Replace spaces is not enought, try this

```
url = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: `replace` is using literals, not regex syntax. Please test your code before posting it.

Comment: Yes sorry, I changed the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
imageUrl = imageUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```