# How to remove and replace a char in a string?

Tags: java, string, char

I am trying to write two methods:

**The first:** take a pre-defined char (a "key character" that the user has chosen) and remove it from a string (also that the user has chosen).

I have tried:

```
theString = theString.replace( keyCharacter, "a");
```

but although the keyCharacter has been predefined as a char, it will not work,and I get this error, *`"The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char, "String)`*

**The second:** replace all the key characters in the string with a new character, let's say an O.

Comment: String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) Use this method which in string class ,remember that this method will return a new String instance.

Comment: Just use one `String#replaceAll()` to achieve both 1 and 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to replace spaces inside string with percentual symbol Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408187/need-to-replace-spaces-inside-string-with-percentual-symbol-java)

Answer (score 2):

`"a"` is a `String`. You want `'a'` (a `char`). Like

```
theString = theString.replace(keyCharacter, 'a');
```

Also, because Java `String` is immutable, you're creating new `String` instances. If you need to replace many `char`(s), I'd prefer [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or a regular expression [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

The 'replace' method of string in java requires both parameter as 'char',
You are passing "a" as a string instead of 'a' as char.

So, Just change it. And check again.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do it in java and the method returns the `String`

To replace the old char with new char

```
replace('a', 'a') ;
```

To replace the old charSequence with new charSequence

```
 replace("aab", "a") ;
```

Use to replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)

```
replaceAll("aa","b");
```