# How to replace specific letters in a string in java?

Tags: java

So I'm having trouble with replacing characters but finding them is finished. My problem is instead of copying only one of the code is copying multiple.

```
String NewText = "";
for( int i=0; i<Str.length(); i++ ) {
    if( Str.charAt(i) == 'a' ) {
        counter++;
        String newText = Str.replace('a', '@');
        NewText=newText;
    } else if( Str.charAt(i) == 'e' ) {
        counter1++;
        String newText1 = Str.replace('e','3');
        NewText=NewText+newText1;
    }
}

System.out.println("Total vowels: "+counterTotal+" | "+counter5+ " y's");
System.out.println(NewText+" | Original text: "+Str);
```

My problem is the NewText variable saves all the text and not just the changed letters. Through trial and error, I would appreciate any help to improve this code for it to work correctly. Imagine the rest of the code, which is just replacing the vowels aeiou but how can I have my code also check for uppercase letters without copy paste?

Comment: Why are you even looping? Just use `replace`.

Comment: On a side note, using both `newText` and `NewText` is an incredibly bad practice.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly, you have counters so are you trying to replace character one by one ?

Comment: Have a look at regular expression and `replace` or `replaceAll`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to replace spaces inside string with percentual symbol Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408187/need-to-replace-spaces-inside-string-with-percentual-symbol-java)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testStr = "TEST";
    int count = count(testStr,'T');
    String newStr = testStr.replaceAll("T", "3");
    System.out.println("Total T: " + count);
    System.out.println("Old:" + testStr +" | New: "+newStr);
}

public static int count(String str, char letter){
    int counter = 0;
    for( int i=0; i<str.length(); i++ ) {
        if( Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i)) == Character.toUpperCase(letter)) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

The method `count` will count how many times the given letter appers in the given str. We call the toUpperCase in the if to compare despite the letter case. Now you are reusing the code for other letter, you dont need to repeat your for loop anymore, just call the method. In the main method, we call the count, and after that we replace the letter using replaceAll, which replaces all the characters in the String for the given parameter. The `String`class is immutable, so, it returns a new String. Here is the output:

```
Total T: 2
Old:TEST | New: 3ES3
```

This solve your problem, right?

Comment: If using Java 8, you could also change your count function to use a functional style..... `return str.chars().filter(num -> num == letter).count();`  However, the return type would be a long instead of an int.